# how to recursively transfer folders between two remote servers on a local machine

Tags: server, ssh, rsync, scp

I want to use a program like rsync or scp to recursively transfer folders from one remote server to another on the shell. I connect from one server usually via sftp and the other via ftp, but I believe I can also ftp and ftp. I have the links to the desired directories. I tried a program like ftprush in windows, but it would connect to both servers, but wouldn't initiate the transfer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I am a fan of `scp` to copy things between servers (who would've thunk it...) (I really only use `rsync` as a backup tool) I've never tried copying between two remote hosts, but I don't see any reason it wouldn't work

`scp -r user1@server1:/path/to/folder user2@server2:/path/to/copy/to`

Comment: I'm getting the following error ssh: Could not resolve hostname ftp: Temporary failure in name resolution. The FTP only server I can access via http. The SFTP one I cannot access via http (error 550) and when I post the url in filezilla it reverts to the home user directory, rather than the linked one.

Comment: what did you type exactly?

Comment: scp -r ftp://username:password@hosting:21/media/sdc1/user ftp://username:password@hosting:21/

Comment: I'm not sure how you transformed `user@server...` to `user:password@hosting`

Comment: I do not have ssh server with password authentication to test, probably the syntax could be `scp -r ssh://user:pwd@host ...`.

Comment: @pa4080 interesting, I've only ever seen it `user@server:path`. Guess it's true, you learn something new everyday :D

Comment: I just suppose, because this syntax works in some other cases :) @Steven, could you verify whether this works, please?